# Booting to Windows Boot Manager removes Ubuntu option from BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.1 on two separate hard drives in my desktop. I noticed an interesting boot pattern that I haven't noticed before. If the Ubuntu boot option shows up in my BIOS, I can select it and boot to the OS just fine; Windows Boot Manager is **not** listed. If, within GRUB, I select the option to boot over to Windows Boot Manager (yes, it is listed here, just not in the BIOS), Windows then loads just fine as well. But then, if I go back into the BIOS, Windows Boot Manager is now available, but Ubuntu is not. So now, the only way for me to get back into Ubuntu is to boot to a live USB, and run boot-repair.

How can I get both options to show up permanently? Or, if that's impossible, how can I enable GRUB to be my default bootloader, and then just use that to load WBM whenever I want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

1- First download boot repair disk from here: [Boot Repair Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

2- Then burn it into a USB or a CD-DVD

3- Boot your computer from that device

4- Choose your language

5- Choose "Recommended Repair"

6- Reboot your computer.

It will fix your grub (I hope)...

Comment: I've already done that, as I described above.

Comment: I sometimes have a kind of problem with windows and ubuntu. In ubuntu, i get mount problem and solve it by ntfsfix. But for the partition windows installed, it doesnt fix. so i will ask you to try: "powercfg /h off" on command prompt, while shutting down the windows. After this, if you see linux grub, so it will mean a mount problem.